# Removing task kills background process when bound

Tags: android, binding, process

#### Background

I have an app that uses two processes:

- UI
- Background

The background process hosts two services:

- A long-running foreground service (started with `startService` and made foreground using `startForeground`), `ImportantService`. It uses `START_STICKY` to ensure it isn't killed if
- A temporary one for inter-process communication, `SettingsService`.

The UI binds to the temporary service in the background process for inter-process communication using `bindService(..., ..., Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)`.

#### Problem

If I open the Recents activity on my phone and swipe to kill/remove my activity after it has bound to `SettingsService`, the entire background process is killed, and `ImportantService` is consequently killed.

#### Symptoms

- `ImportantService` is restarted after being killed, probably due to `START_STICKY`.
- This doesn't happen if the services are moved into the UI process.
- This doesn't happen if I start `SettingsService` via `startService()` but don't bind to it. The problem seems to be triggered by binding to the service.

#### What I've Tried

- Starting `SettingsService` using `startService()` before binding to it using `bindService()`.
- Using each of the available flags for `bindService()`.
- Unbinding from `SettingsService` in `onPause()`. This prevents the problem from happening the first time, but it still happens on subsequent tests.
- Making `SettingsService` bind to itself.

#### Environment

- Device: Sony Xperia M
- OS: Android 5.1.1
- Customisation: Cyanogenmod 12.1
- Also reproduced the problem in Genymotion emulator running Android 4.4.4

#### Logcat Main Buffer Logs

```
06-17 07:27:22.633      678-897/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 7666:com.example.myapp/u0a151 (adj 9): remove task
06-17 07:27:22.650     678-1327/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{3e26d1c9 u0 com.example.myapp/.SettingsActivity}
06-17 07:27:22.769     678-1211/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 32110:com.example.myapp:backgroundprocess/u0a151 (adj 0): remove task
06-17 07:27:22.898     678-1149/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example.myapp/.ImportantService in 1000ms
06-17 07:27:23.979      678-696/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc 7809:com.example.myapp:backgroundprocess/u0a151 for service com.example.myapp/.ImportantService
```

#### Logcat Event Buffer Logs

```
06-17 20:33:08.482 I/am_finish_activity(  678): [0,395523242,1024,com.example.myapp/.SettingsActivity,clear]
06-17 20:33:08.484 I/am_destroy_activity(  678): [0,395523242,1024,com.example.myapp/.SettingsActivity,finish-imm]
06-17 20:33:08.488 I/am_kill (  678): [0,5636,com.example.myapp,9,remove task]
06-17 20:33:08.640 I/dvm_lock_sample(  678): [system_server,1,ActivityManager,142,ActivityManagerService.java,3410,-,8682,28]
06-17 20:33:08.644 I/am_proc_died(  678): [0,5636,com.example.myapp]
06-17 20:33:08.645 I/am_kill (  678): [0,3960,com.example.myapp:backgroundprocess,0,remove task]
06-17 20:33:08.811 I/wm_task_removed(  678): [1024,removeAppToken: last token]
06-17 20:33:08.812 I/wm_task_removed(  678): [1024,removeTask]
06-17 20:33:08.816 I/dvm_lock_sample(  678): [system_server,1,Binder_F,136,ActivityManagerService.java,1230,-,1230,27]
06-17 20:33:08.819 I/am_proc_died(  678): [0,3960,com.example.myapp:backgroundprocess]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an Android bug. I've filed an issue for it at:

[Issue 178057: Process killed when task removed while bound to service with BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178057).

Here are some workarounds taken from the above:

> 1. In the foreground service's `onTaskRemoved()`, launch an activity on task removal
>
>    - Fixes the problem about 75% of the time.
>    - This closes the "Recents" activity on the user, so it alters the normal task-closing experience for the user.
>    - Seems to depend on timing, so it mightn't be a perfect workaround
> 2. In the foreground service's `onTaskRemoved()`, send multiple broadcasts to a registered receiver in the application with the `Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND` flag.
>
>    - Seems to nearly always work, depending on timing and the number of broadcasts you send
> 3. Unbind from the background service before the task is removed

Comment: This is not a bug. You should use startservice() to start a service that you want to keep alive without anything bound to it. If a service is started with bindservice() then android will remove it when it has no bindings left.

Comment: @RocketRandom, the long running service actually was started with `startService()`, but it looks like I didn't mention that in the question, so I've just updated the question. Also, note that the issue isn't that the bound service is removed when unbound, the issue is that the entire *process* is killed when the task is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Merging the two services into one seems to fix the problem, although it's kind of messy.